# Proof with false hypothesis in Isabelle/HOL Isar

Tags: coq, proof, isabelle

I am trying to prove a lemma which in a certain part has a false hypothesis. In Coq I used to write "congruence" and it would get rid of the goal. However, I am not sure how to proceed in Isabelle Isar. I am trying to prove a lemma about my `le` function:

```
primrec le::"nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool" where
"le 0 n = True" |
"le (Suc k) n = (case n of 0 ⇒ False | Suc j ⇒ le k j)"

lemma def_le: "le a b = True ⟷ (∃k. a + k = b)"
proof
  assume H:"le a b = True"
  show "∃k. a + k = b"
  proof (induct a)
    case 0
    show "∃k. 0 + k = b"
    proof -
      have "0 + b = b" by simp
      thus ?thesis by (rule exI)
    qed

    case Suc
    fix n::nat
    assume HI:"∃k. n + k = b"
    show "∃k. (Suc n) + k = b"
    proof (induct b)
      case 0
      show "∃k. (Suc n) + k = 0"
      proof -
        have "le (Suc n) 0 = False" by simp
        oops
```

Note that my `le` function is "less or equal". At this point of the proof I find I have the hypothesis `H` which states that `le a b = True`, or in this case that `le (Suc n) 0 = True` which is false. How can I solve this lemma?

Another little question: I would like to write `have "le (Suc n) 0 = False" by (simp only:le.simps)` but this does not work. It seems I need to add some rule for reducing case expressions. What am I missing?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not that it is hard to get rid of a `False` hypothesis in Isabelle. In fact, pretty much all of Isabelle's proof methods will instantly prove anything if there is `False` in the assumptions. No, the problem here is that at that point of the proof, you don't have the assumptions you need anymore, because you did not chain them into the induction. But first, allow me to make a few small remarks, and then give concrete suggestions to fix your proof.

## A Few Remarks

1. It is somewhat unidiomatic to write `le a b = True` or `le a b = False` in Isabelle. Just write `le a b` or `¬le a b`.
2. Writing the definition in a convenient form is very important to get good automation. Your definition works, of course, but I suggest the following one, which may be more natural and will give you a convenient induction rule for free:

Using the function package:

```
fun le :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ bool" where
  "le 0 n             = True"
| "le (Suc k) 0       = False"
| "le (Suc k) (Suc n) = le k n"
```

3. Existentials can sometimes hide important information, and they tend mess with automation, since the automation never quite knows how to instantiate them.

If you prove the following lemma, the proof is fully automatic:

```
lemma def_le': "le a b ⟷ a + (b - a) = b"
  by (induction a arbitrary: b) (simp_all split: nat.split)
```

Using my function definition, it is:

```
lemma def_le': "le a b ⟷ (a + (b - a) = b)"
  by (induction a b rule: le.induct) simp_all
```

Your lemma then follows from that trivially:

```
lemma def_le: "le a b ⟷ (∃k. a + k = b)"
  using def_le' by auto
```

This is because the existential makes the search space explode. Giving the automation something concrete to follow helps a lot.

## The actual answer

There are a number of problems. First of all, you will probably need to do `induct a arbitrary: b`, since the `b` will change during your induction (for `le (Suc a) b`, you will have to do a case analysis on `b`, and then in the case `b = Suc b'` you will go from `le (Suc a) (Suc b')` to `le a b'`).

Second, at the very top, you have `assume "le a b = True"`, but you do not chain this fact into the induction. If you do induction in Isabelle, you have to chain all required assumptions containing the induction variables into the induction command, or they will not be available in the induction proof. The assumption in question talks about `a` and `b`, but if you do induction over `a`, you will have to reason about some arbitrary variable `a'` that has nothing to do with `a`. So do e.g:

```
assume H:"le a b = True"
thus "∃k. a + k = b"
```

(and the same for the second induction over `b`)

Third, when you have several cases in Isar (e.g. during an induction or case analysis), you have to separate them with `next` if they have different assumptions. The `next` essentially throws away all the fixed variables and local assumptions. With the changes I mentioned before, you will need a `next` before the `case Suc`, or Isabelle will complain.

Fourth, the `case` command in Isar can fix variables. In your `Suc` case, the induction variable `a` is fixed; with the change to `arbitrary: b`, an `a` and a `b` are fixed. You should give explicit names to these variables; otherwise, Isabelle will invent them and you will have to hope that the ones it comes up with are the same as those that you use. That is not good style. So write e.g. `case (Suc a b)`. Note that you do *not* have to fix variables or assume things when using `case`. The `case` command takes care of that for you and stores the local assumptions in a theorem collection with the same name as the case, e.g. `Suc` here. They are categorised as `Suc.prems`, `Suc.IH`, `Suc.hyps`. Also, the proof obligation for the current case is stored in `?case` (not `?thesis`!).

## Conclusion

With that (and a little bit of cleanup), your proof looks like this:

```
lemma def_le: "le a b ⟷ (∃k. a + k = b)"
proof
  assume "le a b"
  thus "∃k. a + k = b"
  proof (induct a arbitrary: b)
    case 0
    show "∃k. 0 + k = b" by simp
  next
    case (Suc a b)
    thus ?case
    proof (induct b)
      case 0
      thus ?case by simp
    next
      case (Suc b)
      thus ?case by simp
    qed
  qed
next
```

It can be condensed to

```
lemma def_le: "le a b ⟷ (∃k. a + k = b)"
proof
  assume "le a b"
  thus "∃k. a + k = b"
  proof (induct a arbitrary: b)
    case (Suc a b)
    thus ?case by (induct b) simp_all
  qed simp
next
```

But really, I would suggest that you simply prove a concrete result like `le a b ⟷ a + (b - a) = b` first and then prove the existential statement using that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is very complete. First of all I must say that I am not interested in automation as I am designing this for a course of Informal and Formal proof, where the aim is not learning how to use Isabelle but learning the art proof. That said, I want to be as explicit as possible with my proofs and have as little automation as possible. I do not want simp to do all the work, like a "black box". In the proof I reach a point where I have the goal `Suc a ≤ 0 ⟹ (⋀b. a ≤ b ⟹ ∃k. a + k = b) ⟹ ∃k. Suc a + k = 0`. How can I solve this goal without just calling simp?

Comment: By `≤`, you mean the `le` you defined in your question? Well, you have to rewrite the `le (Suc a) 0` to `False` and then get rid of the `False` in the assumptions. If you really want to do it by hand:
`apply (subst (asm) le.simps(2))`
`apply (subst (asm) nat.case(1))`
`apply (erule FalseE)`

Comment: Yes, I am referencing my `le` function there. Thank you for your answer. However, I am not sure how to replicate this in Isar (sorry, I am a novice!). I wrote `have "Suc a ≤ 0 = False" by (simp only: le.simps(2) nat.case(1))`. But how can I rewrite this in the assumptions in order to get `False`?

Comment: You can do this in as much detail as you want, but I am not sure how educational it is: `note ‹le (Suc a) 0›` `also have "le (Suc a) 0 ⟷ (case 0 of 0 ⇒ False | Suc x ⇒ le a x)" by (rule le.simps(2))` `also have "… ⟷ False" by (rule nat.case(1))` `finally show ?case by (rule FalseE)`

Comment: It is exactly what I need! I want that much detail. However, I get `Undefined fact: "le (Suc a) 0"` when I write `note "le (Suc a) 0"` even though that is exactly one of my hypothesis!

Comment: `note` is to reference facts that are already there; you need to quote them with backticks or cartouches – not quotation marks, e.g. `‹le (Suc a) 0›`. You could also write `have "le (Suc a) 0" by fact`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99253/discussion-between-martin-copes-and-manuel-eberl).

Answer (score 2):

Manuel Eberl did the hard part, and I just respond to your question on how to try and control `simp`, etc.

Before continuing, I go off topic and clarify something said on another site. The word "a tip" was used to give credit to M.E., but it should have been "3 explanations provided over 2 answers". Emails on mailing lists can't be corrected without spamming the list.

Some short answers are these:

- There is no guarantee of completely controlling `simp`, but attributes `del` and `only`, shown below, will many times control it to the extent that you desire. To see that it's not doing more than you want, traces need to be used; an example of traces is given below.
- To get complete control of proof steps, you would use "controlled" `simp`, along with `rule`, `drule`, and `erule`, and other methods. Someone else would need to give an exhaustive list.
- Most anyone with the expertise to be able to answer "what's the detailed proof of what `simp`, `auto`, `blast`, etc does" will very rarely be willing to put in the work to answer the question. It can be plain, tedious work to investigate what `simp` is doing.
- "Black box proofs" are always optional, as far as I can tell, if we want them to be *and* have the expertise to make them optional. Expertise to make them optional is generally a major limiting factor. With expertise, motivation becomes the limiting factor.

### What's simp up to? It can't please everyone

If you watch, you'll see. People complain there's too much automation, or they complain there's too little automation with Isabelle.

There can never be too much automation, but that's because with Isabelle/HOL, automation is mostly optional. The possibility of *no automation* is what makes proving potentially interesting, but with only *no automation*, proving is nothing but pure tediousness, in the grand scheme.

There are attributes `only` and `del`, which can be used to *mostly* control `simp`. Speaking only from experimenting with traces, even `simp` will call other proof methods, similar to how `auto` calls `simp`, `blast`, and others.

I think you cannot prevent `simp` from calling linear arithmetic methods. But linear arithmetic doesn't apply much of the time.

### Get set up for traces, and even the blast trace

My answer here is generalized for also trying to determine what `auto` is up to. One of the biggest methods that `auto` resorts to is `blast`.

You don't need the `attribute_setup`s if you don't care about seeing when `blast` is used by `auto`, or called directly. Makarius Wenzel took the blast trace out, but then was nice enough to show the code on how to implement it.

Without the blast part, there is just the use of `declare`. In a proof, you can use `using` instead of `declare`. Take out what you don't want. Make sure you look at the new `simp_trace_new` info in the PIDE Simplifier Trace panel.

```
attribute_setup blast_trace = {*
  Scan.lift
   (Parse.$$$ "=" -- Args.$$$ "true" >> K true ||
    Parse.$$$ "=" -- Args.$$$ "false" >> K false ||
    Scan.succeed true) >>
  (fn b => Thm.declaration_attribute (K (Config.put_generic Blast.trace b)))
*}
attribute_setup blast_stats = {*
  Scan.lift
   (Parse.$$$ "=" -- Args.$$$ "true" >> K true ||
    Parse.$$$ "=" -- Args.$$$ "false" >> K false ||
    Scan.succeed true) >>
  (fn b => Thm.declaration_attribute (K (Config.put_generic Blast.stats b)))
*} 
declare[[simp_trace_new mode=full]]
declare[[linarith_trace,rule_trace,blast_trace,blast_stats]]
```

### Try and control simp, to your heart's content with `only` & `del`

I don't want to work hard by using the formula in your question. With simp, what you're looking for with `only` and the traces is that no rule was used that you weren't expecting.

Look at the `simp` trace to see what basic rewrites are done that will always be done, like basic rewrites for `True` and `False`. If you don't even want that, then you have to resort to methods like `rule`.

A starting point to see if you can completely shut down `simp` is `apply(simp only:)`.

Here are a few examples. I would have to work harder to find an example to show when linear arithmetic is automatically being used:

```
lemma
  "a = 0 --> a + b = (b::'a::comm_monoid_add)"
  apply(simp only:) (*
    ERROR: simp can't apply any magic whatsoever.
  *)
oops

lemma
  "a = 0 --> a + b = (b::'a::comm_monoid_add)"
  apply(simp only: add_0) (*
    ERROR: Still can't. Rule 'add_0' is used, but it can't be used first.
  *)
oops

lemma
  "a = 0 --> a + b = (b::'a::comm_monoid_add)"
  apply(simp del: add_0) (*
  A LITTLE MAGIC:
    It applied at least one rule. See the simp trace. It tried to finish
    the job automatically, but couldn't. It says "Trying to refute subgoal 1,
    etc.".
      Don't trust me about this, but it looks typical of blast. I was under
    the impressions that simp doesn't call blast.*)
oops

lemma
  "a = 0 --> a + b = (b::'a::comm_monoid_add)"
by(simp) (*
 This is your question. I don't want to step through the rules that simp
 uses to prove it all.
*)
```

Comment: `simp only:` essentially still does three things (that I can think of): it has loopers (that e.g. perform case splitting if the goal was not solved), it has simprocs, and it calls solvers (like linarith). I don't think you can change that without modifying the simpset in ML. However, if you want a kind of restricted simplifier that uses only the simplification rules that you give it, you can use `apply (subst …)` (for the goal) and `apply (subst (asm) …)` (for the assumptions), or something like `apply (unfold …)`.